# SSIS Redeployment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I finally got my SSIS package deployed to our SQL 2005 server, and I can run it from my ASP.NET 2.0 code.  I needed to change my package after I first set it up.  I double-clicked the `.manifest` file and deployed the package to the same server, but the job is never updated.  It stays in the same state as when I first deployed it.

Is there something I'm missing?  Does my DBA have to do something to make the SSIS job get refreshed?

Comment: I wish I could answer ('cause that would mean I *knew* the answer). I'll be watching....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumedly, you're talking about having the SQL Server Agent job refresh when you republish a package. This won't happen. The job just points at the package, and doesn't need to update whenever the packages do. If you deployed without any errors, the package run will be the latest published package.

If you're publishing to the File System, you can go digging in `%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Packages`. There, you should see the updated `dtsx` files.

If you're publishing to SQL Server, then you need to connect SSMS to your instance of Integration Services, expand the tree to your package, and hit `Reports-->General`. This will tell you the version number. Upon change/deployment, you'll see that number go up. You can also do `select * from msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90` to get the same info.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks again for your help!  Just a little unclear on the last paragraph - expand the tree to your package - is that in SSMS?  or BIDS?  Thanks!

Comment: SSMS, once connected to the SSIS instance. Sorry I wasn't clear!

Comment: Hi again, Eric.  Thanks for your quick response.  As you may have expected, no, we programmers at our company don't have access to that either.  But we did finally get it to work, thanks to your help.  It turns out my package was getting updated when I redeployed, but had an error in it (due to authorization privileges on another server).  I publish my packages to SQL Server.  Thanks again.